# How to append html video tag to a div in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, append

```
import React,{useRef} from "react"

const FuncComp = () => {
 
const videoItems = useRef();
  
const addVideo (stream){
    videoItems.current.append(<video src = {stream}> </video>);     
};

return (
    <div ref = {videoItems}>
      
    </div>
  )
}
```

But addVideo function is not working as i can not append video tag to the div. is there another way to achive this?

Comment: where r you calling addVideo?

Comment: Rename VideoItems to videoItems.

Comment: @Asutosh this is not the whole code but i'm sure that its simple and good enough to explain the question. and i'm calling it on peerjs function where a user sends & receives  stream. and the use of "addVideo" function is to add those streams to the page

Comment: Your code's syntax is not correct,  you are using functional component but defined addVideo as member function

Answer (score 0):

you can write your code like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [videos, setVideos] = useState([]);

  const addVideo = (id, stream) => {
    const videosTemp = [...videos];
    videosTemp.push({ id, stream });

    setVideos(videosTemp);
  };

  const onAddVideoClick = () => {
    const id = uuidv4();
    const stream = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=haMOUb3KVSo";
    addVideo(id, stream);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onAddVideoClick}>Add Video</button>
      {videos.map((video) => {
        <video key={video.id} src={video.src} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Just a little, Curious about it will render all the video by adding into the queue. Please use the Rect.memo to prevent the rendering of existing data.